# Hydration failed after set token to cookie

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am currently using next 14 with app dir and i have component for log in and after log in i set access token to cookie and refresh page but when i refresh  page it throws error hydration failed

here my client side setting value to cookie:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

  // handleFinish
  const handleFinish = async (e: any) => {
    const res = await api.post('/Auth/user/signIn', e)
    if (!res) return
    if (res.status === 200) {
      console.log(res, 'res')
      Cookies.set('access_token', res.data.token,{secure:true,expires:12000})
      toast.success(res.data.message, { position: 'bottom-center' })
      // router.replace('/')
    }
  }
```

i tried set cookie in server component also in client component

i want to set access value which comes from endpoint to cookie then use it in server component also in client component

Answer (score 0):

i found solution for this.

if you are accessing Cookie on client side you should first check it comes true like below:

```
const [cookie,setCookie]=useState()
    
 useLayoutEffect(()=>{
   if(Cookie.get('access_token') return setCookie(Cookie.get('access_token')) 
 },[])
```

it helped me to avoid error.